Block LAN access to a client in Wireguard
I have a Wireguard server running on a raspberri pi on my home LAN. I want to give a relative who lives in a different country access to my VPN, so he can freely use internet services blocked by his local ISP, but I don't want him to have access to devices on my LAN. Is there a way to configure Wireguard server to achieve that?
My server config is :
# wg0.conf

[Interface]
Address = 10.24.36.1/24
MTU = 1420
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = 111

[Peer]
PublicKey = 222
PresharedKey = 333
AllowedIPs = 10.24.36.2/32
Endpoint = 172.19.188.166:11262

[Peer]
PublicKey = 444
PresharedKey = 555
AllowedIPs = 10.24.36.3/32
Endpoint = 172.18.164.218:7833

Typical client config:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 666
Address = 10.24.36.3/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

[Peer]
PublicKey = 777
PresharedKey = 555
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = my-ip.no-ip.com:41234


You have to update the firewall on the machine that acts as a wireguard server.
Lets say your relative is having the ip address 192.168.200.2 and your LAN is located at 192.168.0.0/24.
I would the make the following two rules in this order:
From 192.168.200.2 to 192.168.0.0/24 DENY
From 192.168.200.2 to 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW

The way it works by going top down and matches first rule that fits the bill.
Any ip address not belonging to your LAN will not be matched by the first rule and is therefore allowed to be forwarded.
While any traffic for your LAN will be blocked by the firewall.

I thought about the same thing. I've add a rule to block all trafic to my LAN from wg0 with his IP address. iptables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -s 10.24.36.3 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j DROP Seems to do the trick. I just thought maybe there's a way to do it directly in wireguard config.

Yes and no. You can make a hook for when a connection goes up or down that adds or removes rules to the firewall, but that is honestly too complicated for what you are trying to solve. Wireguard should only concentrate on which remote ip is allowed to contact the gateway via VPN and that includes any LANs on the other side of the VPN. The firewalls job is to act as a traffic cop and decide who goes where depending on where they came from and under which circumstances.

The reason why I will not add hookup rules in wireguard is because of simplicity. It would be a different matter if VPN clients were assigned dynamic IPs, so you could only identify the client by its public key. It is doable but VERY complicated and in that case I would rather just use ipsec for VPN instead as it would be better suited for the task.

@Viktor Wireguard itself has nothing to do with the IP forwarding. It just establishes a tunnel, and it has no facility for destination-based filtering on traffics from a peer. (AFAICT, AllowedIPs=, as the name suggests, does configure a source-based filter. Certainly it couldn't stop the peer from performing source NAT though.)

which remote ip is allowed to contact the gateway I think more precisely, it is "traffics with which source IPs are allowed from each peer respectively". (Not really sure why you mentioned dynamic IPs either. Unlike OpenVPN, Wireguard itself literally doesn't support / leverage anything similar to DHCP.)

identify the client by its public key Also, unless / until you make changes in the server conf, the source IP of the traffics does reflect which client they come from.
